# Mobile application phone, email edit text validation using expressions

Tags: java, android, validation, email, phone-number

I need to validate phone and email Edit texts in android application.

Email text I want it to match the familiar email syntax "example@gmail.com"

Phone text I want it to be like this "xxx-xxx-xxxx" where x is numbers only

I want the validation to happen OnFocusChangeListener

```
phoneNum.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFoucs) {
        if(!hasFoucs){
            Phone = phoneNum.getText().toString();
            if (!Phone.matches("^\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$/")){
                phoneNum.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBABA"));
                Toast.makeText(ctx,"Phone Syntax incorrect",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                flag_phone = 0;
            }
            else {
                phoneNum.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                flag_phone =1;
            }
        } else {
            phoneNum.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
});
```

and for email, I tried this

```
    EmailTxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFoucs) {
            if(!hasFoucs){
                Email = EmailTxt.getText().toString();
                if (!Email.matches("^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$")){
                    EmailTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBABA"));
                    Toast.makeText(ctx,"Email should be 10 numbers",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    flag_email = 0;
                }
                else {
                    EmailTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    flag_email =1;
                }
            } else {
                EmailTxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }

        }
    });
```

if its possible to put the expression in the matches() instead of using other approaches it will be more suitable for me, please.

Comment: !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches(); can be used to validate email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/thyrlian/AwesomeValidation

Use this library to perform validations.

Also see :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html

Patterns in Android.

Hope this helps.